# Assigning a string value to a class in objective c

Tags: objective-c, string

I'm a completely newbie at this so please don't yell at me yet.

What I'm trying to write is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
    int main() {
    int age = 17;

    //I'm trying to assign a string value to a class call name.
    //Now I know there are different types of specifiers: %i for int, %@ for NSString etc.
    //but what I want to do is this

    int name = "PJ" //Which is completely wrong I know but the only other way that I found
                    //is to use NSString but that means I would need to use the NSObject
                    //Library which I don't want to get into yet, I want to keep it simple

    printf("Hello World, my name is %@ and I'm %d years old\n", name, age);
}
```

Comment: `const char *name = "PJ"`

Comment: Or, better in Objective-C, `NSString* name = @"PJ", especially if you're going to use the `%@` formatting code.

Comment: @HotLicks, but in the code comment he specifically says he doesn't want to get into the `NSObject` class yet :)

Comment: Then change the printf to use `%s`, if you don't want to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
const char *name = "PJ"
```

Also, you might want to change your print statement to be:

```
printf("Hello World, my name is %s and I'm %d years old\n", name, age);
```

Otherwise, as commented by @HotLicks below, it would crash.

That's more C than Objective-C, as you probably already deduced :)

Comment: Note that that will crash or print garbage, given the above printf.